# How filter rows by matched values using BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery

```
SELECT 1 as big_id, 1 as temp_id, '101' as names
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,1, 'z3Awwer', 
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,1, 'gA1sd03',
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,2, 'z3Awwer', 
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,2, 'gA1sd03',
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,3, 'gA1sd03',
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,3, 'sAs10sdf4',
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,4, 'sAs10sdf4',
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,5, 'Adf105', 
      UNION ALL SELECT 2,1, 'A1sdf02',
      UNION ALL SELECT 2,1, '345A103',
      UNION ALL SELECT 2,2, '345A103',
      UNION ALL SELECT 2,2, 'A1sd04',
      UNION ALL SELECT 2,3, 'A1sd04',
      UNION ALL SELECT 2,4, '6_0Awe105'
```

I want to filter it by `temp_id` if **all** `names` of one `temp_id` included in some another `temp_id` in partition by `big_id` window. For example I do not need to select **all** rows where `temp_id` = 2 because **all** `names` of `temp_id` = 2 included in  `temp_id` = 1. As well as need to keep all rows of `temp_id` = 1 because this `names` range covers `names` range of `temp_id` = 2

So expected output:

```
SELECT 1 as big_id, 1 as temp_id, '101' as names
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,1, 'z3Awwer', 
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,1, 'gA1sd03',     
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,3, 'gA1sd03',
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,3, 'sAs10sdf4',     
      UNION ALL SELECT 1,5, 'Adf105', 
      UNION ALL SELECT 2,1, 'A1sdf02',
      UNION ALL SELECT 2,1, '345A103',
      UNION ALL SELECT 2,2, '345A103',
      UNION ALL SELECT 2,2, 'A1sd04',      
      UNION ALL SELECT 2,4, '6_0Awe105'
```

How can I make it using BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardsql
with temp as (
  select big_id, temp_id, array_agg(names) names
  from `project.dataset.table`
  group by big_id, temp_id
)
select big_id, temp_id, names 
from (
  select big_id, temp_id, any_value(names) names 
  from (
    select t1.*,
      ( select count(1)
        from t1.names name
        join t2.names name
        using(name)
        where t1.temp_id != t2.temp_id
      ) = array_length(t1.names) as flag
    from temp t1 
    join temp t2
    using (big_id)
  )
  group by big_id, temp_id
  having countif(flag) = 0
), unnest(names) names
```

If to apply above to sample data from your question - the output is

[image]